# Are there any current examples of English "Back-Slang"?

Tags: slang

Other languages feature words pronounced as their inverse (such as [verlan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan) and [fika](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fika_%28coffee_break%29)).  What are some examples of this in English?  The closest example I can think of it Pig Latin.

Comment: Verlan doesn’t really invert the pronunciation of the words, it “merely” inverts the order of the *syllables* (ver-lan => lan-ver = sloppy pronunciation of l’invers = the inverse).

Comment: I've encountered modified forms of the word "Dyslexic" such as "Lysdexic" and "Slydexic." Another example is the phrase: "Palindromes are rasemordnilap."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Yob* is originally back-slang for *boy*, as is *yennap* for *penny*. In the phrase *dab it up with* (to sleep with) the dab was originally *deb*, backslang for *bed*. Of these, so far as I know, only *yob* remains in current usage.

For more backslang words, see here... http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/fun/wordplay/back_slang.html

Comment: Your "ixnay" example is better known as Pig Latin, which the OP referenced already.... :-)

Comment: @Hellion, is it? Thank you, I didn't know that sort of thing had a name. I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: It's usually formulated the other way around from how you had described it: move the initial consonant to the end and add "ay" to that consonant.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin (ixnay is explicitly mentioned as a pig-latin word that as entered the common vernacular).

Comment: @Hellion, Thanks. Very interesting page, that one.

Comment: @Hellion, @Brian: as I’ve explained in the comment to the question, the formation of “ixnay” is almost precisely the same as that of verlan which also just inverts the syllables, not all the letters so I think it fits here.

Answer (score 4):

Polari has the word *eek*, from *ecaf*.

> How bona to vada your dolly old eek!

Admittedly, that's Julian & Sandy, but I think it also counts as real Polari.

Comment: Yep, that's completely authentic Polari for "How good to see your pretty face" with "old" as a common filler much as it is in much British slang.

Comment: *esong* or *sedon* for "nose" and *riah* for "hair" would be other Polari examples of backslang.

Answer (score 0):

In 1994, Tom Petty's censored radio version of "[You Don't Know How It Feels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Don%27t_Know_How_It_Feels)" featured the word "joint" reversed to avoid overt drug references in the song.  It sounded like "noij".

In 2003, Missy Elliot's song "[Work It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_It_%28Missy_Elliott_song%29)" also featured lyrics in reverse.  Most listeners mistakenly thought that it was gibberish, or were unable to derive the meaning.

Comment: And ""Yvan eht Nioj" from the Simpsons   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Kids_on_the_Blecch

Comment: Nice!  I forgot about that one!

Answer (score 0):

How about "naff" from fanny? Still in common use in Britain.

Comment: Do you have some support for this etymology?

Comment: No! And it's a very fair question. It's one of those bits of pub etymology, I got told it in a pub and it obviously works (ie naff is - sort of - fanny backwards). With a similar lack of authority - or maybe random geezers in London pubs should have more authority on slang? ;-) - I was told that a "dab hand" meant a bad hand and referred to someone who might pick your pocket or otherwise thieve - certainly London slang for fingers or fingerprints is "dabs". But maybe I'm just spreading pure rumours!?